# How do I extend JavaScript Objects

Tags: javascript, dom

I might be using the wrong words to describe my question.

In my browser's developer tools, under DOM, I want to extend one of those already there.  For instance, if I write this:

```
var MY = function () { 
    function sayWhat() {
        console.log('Chicken butt');
    };

    return {
        sayWhat: sayWhat
    };
}();
```

Then MY appears in the DOM.  Now, to avoid clutter and keep things organized, I want another DOM thingy to extend it.  Like this:

```
var MY.CUSTOM = function () { 
    function sayWhy() {
        console.log('Chicken thigh');
    };

    return {
        sayWhy: sayWhy
    };
}();
```

So that I could run MY.sayWhat() and MY.CUSTOM.sayWhen()

What is the right way for me to phrase this question, how do I do what I want, and am I following best practices?

Comment: These are not DOM elements. These are plain functions, and your exact syntax will work just fine (except the part that isn't formatted as code lacks a few parentheses).

Comment: Also, `MY.CUSTOM().sayWhen` would be `undefined`, because `sayWhy` is the function it returns.

Comment: @JanDvorak I assumed I was making a mistake because this javascript executes with an error: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement var MY.CUSTOM = function () {

Comment: You cannot declare a variable with a name like that. What you're trying to do, I think, is add a property called "CUSTOM" to an existing object. You don't do that with a `var` statement.

Comment: oh, missed that. Drop the `var` as `CUSTOM` is a property of `MY`, not a local variable.

Comment: Thanks that did it.  @Pointy if you want to put that as an answer, I'll upvote it and mark is as correct.

Comment: I don't think that comment is worth keeping.  ;)

Comment: I would recommend changing the title to "How do I extend JavaScript Objects" to remove confusion with the DOM elements

Comment: Yup, good suggestion.  Did that.  Thanks

Comment: I agree this probably should have been closed because it's unlikely to help others, although that is debatable - the "How do I extend stuff I see in the DOM tab" question may well be how many beginners start messing with Javascript and DOM elements. You are at the beginning - look up Javascript: classes, namespaces, and requires/provide. This is probably also a place where paying someone who knows JS well to teach you might be wise. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first question, these are not quite DOM objects but rather just plain JavaScript objects in the global scope. This means your objects will be accessible anywhere you run JavaScript on the page. To read more about JavaScript scope, read through this article: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

As for what you are trying to do, this is called object inheritance and actually has many different ways to be accomplished in JavaScript. If you would like a simple solution, I would suggest John Resig's solution found here: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

This will allow you to create one object and extend it like so:

```
var My = Class.extend({
  sayWhat: function () {
    console.log("Chicken butt");
  }
});

var MyCustom = My.extend({
  sayWhen: function () {
    console.log("Chicken thigh");
  }
});

var m = new My();
m.sayWhat(); // => "Chicken butt"

var m2 = new MyCustom();
m2.sayWhen(); // => "Chicken thigh"
m2.sayWhat(); // => "Chicken butt"
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for politely answering my question.  I learned a lot from this thread.  Looking at you @JanDvorak :)